# Use PowerShell to enumerate Linux SMB shares

Tags: powershell, wmi, smb

I can list my own computer's shares no problem with:

```
gwmi Win32_Share
```

But when I try

```
gwmi Win32_Share -computer myserver
```

Where `myserver` is an HP MediaVault mv2120 running BusyBox. I get back the response: `Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)`

Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "W" in WMI stands for "Windows," and while SAMBA does a half-decent job at getting server message block (SMB) working, it does not implement WMI on Linux. Not the same interface/protocol unfortunately.

If you want to view SAMBA shares from windows, use NET VIEW \\1.2.3.4 where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of your Unix box.

Answer (score 2):

No.. There is a wmiclient package available for Linux. Using that we can communicate Windows from Linux.

The RPC server is unavailable: We have to start RPC related services and WMI service in Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO - Linux does not have a WMI service.

Get-WMIObject only works against Windows systems (until someone in the Linux community implements WMI!)